# Is there an online command reference for vim-cmd in ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi

After asking several questions about the ESXi command line tool `vim-cmd` I was wondering: is there an (online) command reference for this utility? I can find lots of info for specific commands and some quickstart tutorials, but no complete reference documentation. Is something like that available?

Answer (score 2):

Your google-foo is poor :)

[Clicky](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp) - it's the 'vSphere Command-Line Interface Reference' you need.

Comment: Actually, the `vim-cmd` options aren't well documented. [There are tidbits out there](http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/11/vmware-esxi-vim-cmd-command-a-quick-tutorial/), but the scare documentation is for a reason. There are very few cases when you'd need to use them directly. PowerCLI is really what VMware is forcing people to adopt.

Comment: PowerCLI implies Windows, not great for those of us who aren't using it.